# querySelectorAll returns null

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

I am trying to select all P tags, but when I console log it returns zero. Any ideas why?

```
p = document.querySelectorAll("p")
console.log(p)
```

The result is empty nodelist

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Plan your project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/style.css">
    <script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="card"></p>
    <p class="card"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps your script runs before the DOM is ready?

Comment: Ensure that the query is performed after the HTML is loaded.

Comment: (Rolled back the edit which removed the problem from the code)

Comment: yes, I had to move my script to the bottom of the file